# Upgrade to SharePoint 2013

Tags: upgrade

I've a very simple question. I need to upgrade my SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I saw the documentation. Does it mean that a need a new machine for SP2013 and another SQL rather than the existing one?

Thanks in advance.

Tiago